# How to use Sagepay (Direct) integration with AWS Loadbalanced

Tags: amazon-web-services, opayo

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which we have setup through Elastic Load balancer on AWS which works great.

However to take online payments via Sagepay Direct integration, we have had to setup an Elastic IP on to a 'master' instance. This is because Sagepay will only allow requests from a known IP (or IP range I believe) and as far as I know, you will never know the IP of the instance the load balancer throws you on.

Before you ask, Sagepay will not allow me to add a A or C record :(

I can live with this, BUT as my application gets busier it's a shame I cant load balance the payments system and make use of the cloud facilities (auto scaling, etc)

Any thoughts on how to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

After following an AWS seminar, I was informed that AWS publish the IP ranges and these can be added to Sagepay.

Here they are for your reference! [AWS EC2 IP ranges](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701)

Hope that helps!